How to get the value of a variable that its name contained from another variable in tcsh?
I have the following script in tcsh:
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -f

set groups = (one two three four)

foreach group ($groups)
    set go = "go_$group"
    eval "set val = $go"
    if ( $?val ) then
        echo "val is: \$$val"
    endif
end

the output I'm getting is not the output I want. I'm getting:
val is: \7553go_one
val is: \7553go_two
val is: \7553go_three
val is: \7553go_four
I understand that 7553 is the pid...
How can I get the value of each variable go_one, go_two...?
Thanks!

Why do you tag bash?
